# jquery not responding on select box retrived from a PHP script with jquery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden div on a admin page. The div reveal itself when an image-link on the site is clicked. The content of the div is loaded with a jquery.load() call to a PHP script which in return send back the HTML-form for the correspodning link. In this way I have constructed an control panel for the admin. When the admin click on an icon a box appears on top of the page and the content is a HTML form where the admin can make settings to the site. I have already made two links that works perfectly.

However, now, I need to make a third form which contains two select boxes.
The content of the second select box has to be dependant on the choice of the first select box. The class of the first select box is "target".
I therefore need to use the jquery code:

```
$('.target').change(function()
```

However this doesn't work since the select box was retrieved with a jquery.load(). It's like jquery can't "see" the select box at all.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn about the power of [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("change", ".target", function() { });
```

Comment: EPIC! I thought I had to rewrite everything. Thank you so much!